# Why we have to close objects under the finally {} block?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch

Can someone explain why #1 approach is better than #2?

## 1

```
try
{

}
catch
{
}
finally
{
reader.Close();  
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
}
```

## 2

```
try
{

reader.Close();  
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();

}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: The better approach would be to use `using` clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `reader.Close()` raises an exception, both of your options will never close `dataStream` or `response`.

However, in your #2 option, if code prior to `reader.Close()` raises an exception, no objects will be closed.  In #1, you at least guarantee that you'll call `reader.Close()` always, even if something else raises an exception.

In general, though, any object with a `Close()` method *should* also implement `Close` via `IDisposable.Dispose()`, in which case I would always prefer to use `using` instead of either of these options:

```
using(var reader = CreateReader())
{
  using(var dataStream = CreateDataStream(reader))
  {
    using(var response = CreateResponse(dataStream))
    {
       // Use objects
    }
  }
}
```

This will enforce that all objects are properly closed, but is cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer approach 3

```
using(var reader = ...)
using(var dataStream = ...)
using(var response = ...)
{
    //...
}//all disposed (and implicitly closed) at the end of this scope
```

Using this construct, the compiler converts to approximately this:

```
var reader = ...;
var dataStream = ...;
var response = ...;
try
{
    //...
    //even if an error happens here
}
finally
{
   //this code still runs before control leaves this method.
   reader.Close();  
   dataStream.Close();
   response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Actually, not quite.  Using the 3 usings it generates 3 nested try/finally blocks, meaning an exception raised in the `Close` method of the reader doesn't prevent the `Close` method of the response from being closed.  It's actually *better* than the OP's example.

Comment: It was too painful to write out in longhand, so I opted for "approximately" instead. Thanks for this addition. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If an exception occurs anywhere in your try block before all the objects are closed, they won't be closed. The finally block allows you to perform clean-up should an exception be raised in your try block.

As others have mentioned, the `using` approach is the way I go with my own code. The compiler translates the `using` into `try{} finally{}` blocks for you. Check out the following MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Try block is designed to handle possible failures, it's important to handle both a successful and unsuccessful case.  Items inside the Try block might get called, they might not - depending on if and where a failure takes place.

By placing closure statements into the finally block, you ensure the statements will always be called, whether or not the Try section was successful.  This way, you won't leave reader, datastream, and response left open - even if a failure did take place.

Comment: (That being said, the `using` solution is still much better suited to your needs. But I hope this answers your question anyways.)